# Angular Node Routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I've node on server and Angular on client...

angular routes:

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/index.html'

        });
        $routeProvider.when('/todo',
            {
                templateUrl: 'templates/todo.html',
                controller:"TodoController"

            });
        $routeProvider.when('/admin',
            {
                templateUrl: 'templates/admin.html'

            });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });
```

on server side I've defined a route for '/todo'

```
app.use('/todo', todo);
```

and My todo File is

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
todo = require('../controllers/todo'),
winston = require('../../server/config/winston');

// GET users listing. 

router.get('/', todo.list);
router.post('/:id', todo.save);
router.delete('/:id', todo.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

**My Problem**

if I go to home page it works fine and data shows along with loaded Pages i.e if I Enter localhost/3000/ then by default it redirects to /todo and works perfectly.

If i enter localhost/3000/todo then i only see plain text on page that is data returned from server rather then HTML page that i can see above.

I don't know whats wrong with it...

**Edit**
My Todo Controller

```
    var db = require('../config/sequelize'),
    StandardError = require('standard-error');
var winston = require('winston');


exports.save = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.send("Please Login");
    }
    console.log("in create", req.body);
    var _task = {
        task: req.body.task,
        UserId: req.user.id
    }

    console.log(req.user);
    db.Todo.create(_task).then(function (todo) {

        if (!todo) {
            return res.send(new StandardError('Cannot insert'));
        } else {
            console.log(req.body);
            return res.send(todo);
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.send({
            errors: err,
            status: 500
        });
    });
};

exports.list = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.user || req.user.isAdmin) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
    console.log(db.User);

    db.Todo.findAll({where: {UserId: req.user.id}}).then(function (todo) {
        console.log(todo);
        res.jsonp(todo);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.send([{task: "No Data"}]);
    });
};
exports.delete = function (req, res) {

    db.Todo.destroy({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id,
            UserId: req.user.id
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

        console.log("deleted");
        res.send(response + " Record Deleted");


        //db.Todo.findAll().then(function (todo) {
        //   res.jsonp(todo);
        // }).catch(function (err) {
        //    return res.render('error', {
        //         error: err,
        //         status: 500
        //       });
        //  });

    });
};
```

Comment: Please include '../controllers/todo'

Comment: I added my todo Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are confused with the angular routes and the server routes.
Use **localhost/#!/todo** for your todo template and **localhost/todo** for invoking server

Comment: yeah it worked. turned out that node routes get priorty over angular when route in node and angular are same....

Comment: @WaqasNoor There is nothing like priority in this case. The URL for trigerring the node and angular routes are different. Note the **/#!/** in angular routes